# Is there anyway in Rubymine to totally disable softwraps?

Tags: rubymine

I can turn them off for each editor I open but is there a way to remove softwraps all together?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `File` | `Settings` | `Editor` to disable **soft wraps** globally and permanently:

[image: soft wraps]

Comment: Thank you ... must have gone right side of the preferences screen blind!!

Comment: Note; Search for 'wrap' in RubyMine displays a settings hierarchy. To find this setting, do NOT look at the leaf node, but instead the parent! That really has been throwing me off.